# ORACLE SQL Compare Year Range Trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

Trying to get Oracle to Get a date set it to year only and compare to a value inserted or updated into my database before hand
This is what I have tried so far. But I seem to be stuck
Any assistance would be great, Thanks

```
create or replace
TRIGGER CHECK_YEAR_DIFF
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF YEAROFPERSON ON PERSON 
FOR EACH ROW 

Currentdate Date; 
Playeryrborn_Var Integer;

Begin

Currentdate := TRUNC(Sysdate,'YYYY');
YEAROFPERSON_var := new.YEAROFPERSON;

  IF (currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var <= 40) AND (currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var => 16) THEN 

  dbms_Output.Put_Line('Year of Birth Updated Successfully');

  ELSE

  dbms_output.put_line('Year of Birth Failed to Successfully Update');

  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. I am not sure where I have gone wrong :S

Comment: @MattLaw: "doesnt seem to work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Obviously you are using an undeclared variable. But this can’t be your problem, right?

Comment: Ok well, I get a compile error , doesnt actually tell me where my error is. If I attempt to update into the database I get "SQL Error: ORA-04098" Which basically says I have failed at something in my trigger code

Comment: run `show errors` to get a detailed error message.

Comment: @kmkaplan I did just notice I was missing a Declare. Ill have a look into that and try again . Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF (currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var <= 40) AND (currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var => 16)

replace with the following

IF (currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var <= 40) AND (currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var >= 16)

Comment: Cheers @Sribharath Reddy Peketi

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the line:
    currentDate - YEAROFPERSON_var <= 40

To:

```
cast(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') as int) - YearOfPerson_Var <= 40
```

Comment: using `extract(year from sysdate)` would be a bit easier I think